# Putting footer on dynamically growing ListView Android App

Tags: java, android, listview

So, I have a listview. It loads 10 rows at a time from a server. When the user scrolls to the bottom, it will load 10 more. When there are no more rows to add, I want it to display a footerview that says "End of Results". Therefore, I **cannot** add the footerview right when I  set the adapter because then it will say "End of Results" after the first 10 rows and there might be more results to add. Here is my code:

This is what I tried, no errors but footerview doesn't display.

```
        if (finished == 1) {
            Log.d("Test", "at the end of listview");
            footerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.listview_footer, listView, false);
            listView.addFooterView(footerView);
        }
```

and Test    at the end of listview is logged so I know the it is at the end. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    arrayOfLocations = new ArrayList<Location>();

    startLoop = 0;
    endLoop = 10;

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    adapter = new LocationAdapter(this, arrayOfLocations);

    FillLocations myFill = new FillLocations();
    myFill.execute();

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            // if user scrolls...
            if (listView != null
                    && listView.getAdapter() != null
                    && listView.getChildAt(listView.getChildCount() - 1) != null
                    && listView.getLastVisiblePosition() == listView
                            .getAdapter().getCount() - 1
                    && listView.getChildAt(listView.getChildCount() - 1)
                            .getBottom() <= listView.getHeight()
                    && finished == 0) {
                startLoop += 10;
                endLoop += 10;
                FillLocations myList = new FillLocations();
                myList.execute();
            }
        }
    });
}

private class FillLocations extends
        AsyncTask<Integer, Void, ArrayList<Location>> {

    int finished = 0;

    // Decode image in background.
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Location> doInBackground(Integer... params) {

                ...

        // parse json data
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            // if there are less than 10 listings left (no more results)
            if (jArray.length() < endLoop) {
                endLoop = jArray.length();
                finished = 1;
            }

            for (int i = startLoop; i < endLoop; i++) {
                final JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                // add rows to adapter
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return arrayOfLocs;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Location> result) {

        //if it is at the end, add the footer
        if (finished == 1) {
            Log.d("End", "at the end");
            footerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.listview_footer, listView, false);
            listView.addFooterView(footerView);
        }
        for (Location location : result)
            adapter.add(location);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You add the footerview to listview but not refresh the adapter.So after you added the listview you must notify that listview changed with:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

So your code must be like this:

```
if (finished == 1) {
        Log.d("Test", "at the end of listview");
        footerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.listview_footer, listView, false);
        listView.addFooterView(footerView);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

EDIT:

Try this at onPostExecute()

```
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Location> result) {

     arrayOfLocations.addAll(result);
     if (finished == 1) {
        Log.d("End", "at the end");
        footerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.listview_footer, listView, false);
        listView.addFooterView(footerView);
    }
    adapter = new LocationAdapter(context, arrayOfLocations);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Erase this line on onCreate()

```
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately I have tried this and it still does not work

Comment: Is if true,is it log "at the end ..."?

Comment: Yes, it does log at the end

Comment: also, when I add the footerview, the adapter isn't changed, so calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); is essentially useless, right?